# Excel VBA: Defining listbox in worksheet and assign selected items to array

Tags: vba, excel

I have search google and stackoverflow fairly extensively, yet I'm still getting errors.  I believe my mistake is in defining the listbox, TestLB which is in sheet "Layout" (Sheet4).  I've tried putting the code in my Sheet code and the module code.

```
Sub Reserve_Click()

Dim SuggestList As MSForms.ListBox
Set SuggestList = Worksheets("Layout").TestLB

Dim Size As Integer
Size = SuggestList.ListCount - 1

ReDim ReserveAry(0 To Size) As String
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To Size
          If SuggestList.Selected(i) Then
             ReserveAry(i) = SuggestList.Selected(i).Value 

              Worksheets("Suggestions").Cell(i + 1, 3) = ReserveAry(i)
          End If
      Next i
End Sub
```

I'm getting a "compile error: Invalid Qualifier" on 
`ReserveAry(i) = SuggestList.Selected(i).Value`

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the way that you are identifying the values in the listbox to be added to the array. `SuggestList.Selected(i)` returns true or false, and does not have a value property.

Instead, the code should read `ReserveAry(i) = SuggestList.List(i)`

The code may still be somewhat flawed. You loop through the items in the listbox, then add only the ones selected into an array, using their position in the listbox. For example, if item 1 and item 3 are selected, the array will look like: `Res(0) = "Item 1"; Res(1) = ""; Res(2) = "Item 3"` Do you expect those empty array values?

Comment: I see what you mean about removing the .value and the empty entries in the array.  However removing the .value I am still getting "Object does not support this property or method".  As I was mentioning I think I improperly am declaring the listbox, because when commenting the for loop and logic I am still getting errors.  So I guess my question is does the:

`Dim SuggestList As MSForms.ListBox`

`Set SuggestList = Worksheets("Layout").TestLB` 
seem ok?

Comment: I used the same declaration method as your own in my test code and it worked fine. You not only have to remove `.Value`. You have to use the `.List(I)` property. `.Selected` only tells you whether or not the item is selected or not.